# Linker not including unreffrenced array

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker

I have an array in my code which is not called by any function but I need this array, as it is array of address of executables, which microprocessor will call

My query is while I compile the array it is visible in .a file (library) but when I link all the .a files this array does not comes in the final .bin file.
It comes when I use it somewhere but otherwise it is not coming in final .bin file

Answer (score 1):

The linker only includes used objects in the final binary, if the array isn't used it won't be included.

Cast it to void somewhere:

```
 main()
   {
    (void)funcarray;

   }
```

then it will count as being used.